# When using Collections.sort(), it sorts and prints the hashcode

Tags: java, sorting, interface, comparable

I was working with one example where it uses ArrayList contains new instances and using Collections.sort() method using the comparable interface. I dont know why it prints out the hashcode when it sorts and where the bug in my code. Can anyone please find out the mistake and explain me in detail.

**SortFruitObject.java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class SortFruitObject{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Fruit> frui   =   new ArrayList<Fruit>();

        frui.add(new Fruit("Pine", "PineDesc", 500));
        frui.add(new Fruit("Apple", "AppleDesc", 400));
        frui.add(new Fruit("Banana", "BananaDesc", 450));
        frui.add(new Fruit("JackFruit", "JackFruitDesc", 300));

        Collections.sort(frui);
        System.out.println(frui);
    }
}
```

**Fruit.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{
    private String fruitName;
    private String fruitDesc;
    private int fruitQuantity;

    public int compareTo(Fruit f){
        return fruitName.compareTo(f.getFruitName());
    }

    public Fruit(String fruitName, String fruitDesc, int fruitQuantity){
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
        this.fruitQuantity = fruitQuantity;
    }
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName){
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }
    public void setFruitDesc(String fruitDesc){
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
    }
    public void setFruitQuantity(int fruitQuantity){
        this.fruitQuantity  =   fruitQuantity;
    }
    public String getFruitName(){
        return fruitName;
    }
    public String getFruitDesc(){
        return fruitDesc;
    }
    public int getFruitQuantity(){
        return fruitQuantity;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Fruit@36422510, Fruit@308f5944, Fruit@132d9844, Fruit@1667a232]
```

Comment: You need to override `toString` method.

Comment: Super Rohit.  It works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` method to print pretty output, by default it considers Object's toString() which is implemented like

```
   public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
   }
```

and so the output

Comment: +1 Thats Right. But your code didn't workout.  Here is what i used now.

`public String toString(){
  return fruitName + " " + fruitDesc + " " + fruitQuantity + "\n";
 }`

Comment: @JavaBeginer. He has given how the default `toString` looks like, not how you should do. This is what you need to override, which you have done now.